# How to label same pandas dataframe rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe like this:

```
log  apple   watermelon  orange  lemon  grapes

1      1         1         yes     0      0
1      2         0         1       0      0
1     True       0         0       0      2
2      0         0         0       0      2
2      1         1         yes     0      0
2      0         0         0       0      2
2      0         0         0       0      2
3     True       0         0       0      2
4      0         0         0       0      2.1
4      0         0         0       0      2.1
```

How can I label the rows that are the same, for example:

```
log   apple   watermelon  orange  lemon  grapes   ID

1      1         1         yes     0      0      1
1      2         0         1       0      0      2
1     True       0         0       0      2      3
2      0         0         0       0      2      4
2      1         1         yes     0      0      1
2      0         0         0       0      2      4
2      0         0         0       0      2      4
3     True       0         0       0      2      3
4      0         0         0       0      2.1    5
4      0         0         0       0      2.1    5
```

I tried to:

```
df['ID']=df.groupby('log')[df.columns].transform('ID')
```

And

```
df['personid'] = df['log'].clip_upper(2) - 2*d.duplicated(subset='apple')
df
```

However, the above doesnt work because I literally have a lot of columns.

But its not giving me the expected output. Any idea of how to group and label this dataframe?

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643790/pandas-label-duplicates

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I have 500 columns @skrubber

Comment: You may want to take a look to [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) Pandas functions.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
x = io.StringIO("""log  apple   watermelon  orange  lemon  grapes

1      1         1         yes     0      0
1      2         0         1       0      0
1     True       0         0       0      2
2      0         0         0       0      2
2      1         1         yes     0      0
2      0         0         0       0      2
2      0         0         0       0      2
3     True       0         0       0      2
4      0         0         0       0      2.1
4      0         0         0       0      2.1""")
df2 = pd.read_table(x, delim_whitespace=True)
```

You can first use `transform` with tuple to make each row *hashable* and comparable, and then play with indexes and `range` to create unique ids

```
f = df2.transform(tuple,1).to_frame()
k = f.groupby(0).sum()
k['id'] = range(1,len(k.index)+1)
```

And finally

```
df2['temp_key'] = f[0]
df2 = df2.set_index('temp_key')
df2['id'] = k.id
df2.reset_index().drop('temp_key', 1)

    log     apple   watermelon  orange  lemon   grapes  id
0   1       1       1           yes     0       0.0     1
1   1       2       0           1       0       0.0     2
2   1       True    0           0       0       2.0     3
3   2       0       0           0       0       2.0     4
4   2       1       1           yes     0       0.0     5
5   2       0       0           0       0       2.0     4
6   2       0       0           0       0       2.0     4
7   3       True    0           0       0       2.0     6
8   4       0       0           0       0       2.1     7
9   4       0       0           0       0       2.1     7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... but for some reason my id column is full of `NaN` values

Comment: @tumbleweed Thats odd. Have you run the code step by step? Maybe you can spot something wrong in the process? Lets put it this way: in the end, you `k.id` should be a series of ids, and your `df` should have the same index as k

Comment: I tried to check the problem but apparently the `k.id` is not working..

Comment: @tumbleweed It is hard to diagnose without looking at the data :/ But this code/approach works. Maybe you have some different indexes or one or two details that would differ, but the idea is that it should be adaptable

Comment: @tumbleweed what do you mean "touched"? the log column is the same :)

Comment: For example, look rows `2` and `7` they're the same if you dont consider the `log` column. Therefore, they should have the same `id`.