# How to assign a unique ID to detect repeated rows in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a large pandas dataframe, with several columns pretty much like this:

```
A      B         C    D   

John   Tom       0    1
Homer  Bart      2    3
Tom    Maggie    1    4 
Lisa   John      5    0
Homer  Bart      2    3
Lisa   John      5    0
Homer  Bart      2    3
Homer  Bart      2    3
Tom    Maggie    1    4
```

How can I assign an unique id to each repeated row? For example:

```
A      B         C    D      new_id

John   Tom       0    1.2      1
Homer  Bart      2    3.0      2
Tom    Maggie    1    4.2      3
Lisa   John      5    0        4
Homer  Bart      2    3        5
Lisa   John      5    0        4
Homer  Bart      2    3.0      2
Homer  Bart      2    3.0      2
Tom    Maggie    1    4.1      6
```

I know that I can use `duplicate` to detect the duplicated rows, however I can not visualize were are reapeting those rows. I tried to:

```
df.assign(id=(df.columns).astype('category').cat.codes)
df
```

However, is not working. How can I get a unique id for detecting groups of duplicated rows?

Comment: In your example, I believe `new_id` should be 1, 2, 3, 4, **2**, etc ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to label same pandas dataframe rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976954/how-to-label-same-pandas-dataframe-rows)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For small dataframes, you can convert your rows to tuples, which can be hashed, and then use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html).

```
df['new_id'] = pd.factorize(df.apply(tuple, axis=1))[0] + 1
```

`groupby` is more efficient for larger dataframes:

```
df['new_id'] = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), sort=False).ngroup() + 1
```

Answer (score 8):

Group by the columns you are trying to find duplicates over and use `ngroup`:

```
df['new_id'] = df.groupby(['A','B','C','D']).ngroup()
```