# Python random.shuffle does not give exact unique values to the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, random

I am making a dummy dataset of list of companies as user_id, the jobs posted by each company as job_id and c_id as candidate id. 
I have already achieved the first two steps and my dataset looks like below.

```
user_id         job_id
0   HP          HP2
1   Microsoft   Microsoft4
2   Accenture   Accenture2
3   HP          HP0
4   Dell        Dell4
5   FIS         FIS1
6   HP          HP0
7   Microsoft   Microsoft4
8   Dell        Dell2
9   Accenture   Accenture0
```

Also they are shuffled. now i wish to add a random candidate id to this dataset in such a way that no c_id is repeated to a particular job_id.

My approach for this is as follows.
joblist is a list of all job_ids.

> ```
> for i in range(50):
>     l = list(range(0,len(df[df['job_id'] == joblist[i]])))
>     random.shuffle(l)
>     df['c_id'][df['job_id'] == joblist[i]] = l
> ```

after which i tested it as

> len(df['c_id'][df['job_id'] == joblist[0]])

output = 168

> df['c_id'][df['job_id'] == joblist[0]].nunique()

output = 101

and the same is happening with all values. i have rechecked the uniqueness of `l` after each step and its 168 unique values. 
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are trying to achieve. What should the resulting dataframe look like for your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique IDs are provided by basic `pd` functions, so you don't need anything fancy. Solutions vary in efficiency based on how big your `df` is.

```
# Hashing for small datasets:
df['new_id'] = pd.factorize(df.apply(tuple, axis=1))[0] + 1

# Grouping for larger datasets:
df['new_id'] = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), sort=False).ngroup() + 1

# Assign:
df.assign(id=(#Some combo of columns).astype('category').cat.codes)
```

Further reading:
[Q: [Pandas] How to efficiently assign unique ID to individuals with multiple entries based on name in very large df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685254/q-pandas-how-to-efficiently-assign-unique-id-to-individuals-with-multiple-ent)

[How to assign a unique ID to detect repeated rows in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51110171/how-to-assign-a-unique-id-to-detect-repeated-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe)